# Diagonalizable matrix over R

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, diagonalization

I had study about solving linear difference equation system by using results of linear algebra. 
But I have a problem with the following exercise:

Suppose that $A$ is a matrix with real entries, $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ and its characteric polynomial is separable over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Please give me some hint!

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $P,Q\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $P+iQ\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $(P+iQ)^{-1}A(P+iQ)=diag((\lambda_i))$, where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ (why?).

Show that, for every $u\in\mathbb{R}$, $A(P+uQ)=(P+uQ)D$.

Show that there is $u\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $P+uQ\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Conclude.